# Jquery - Remove matched text only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The code below runs through a list of items that have the class .removeFood. If the clicked food name matches the items on the list it is replaced with blank text.

**Example list:**

Nachos

Fries

Nachos

Burger

Nachos

**The problem:** 
If there are duplicates on the list it removes all of the matches. So in the list above it would remove all 3 "nachos" - How do I only remove the first match?

```
    $(".removeFood").click(function() {    
        $(this).text('')     
        if (food1.trim() == removeThis.trim()){
           $("#newFoodName1" ).text('')
        }        
        if (food2.trim() == removeThis.trim()){
           $("#newFoodName2" ).text('')
        }         
        if (food3.trim() == removeThis.trim()){
           $("#newFoodName3" ).text('')
        }         
        if (food4.trim() == removeThis.trim()){
           $("#newFoodName4" ).text('')
        }        
        if (food5.trim() == removeThis.trim()){
           $("#newFoodName5" ).text('')        
        }        
    })
```

Comment: What are `food1`, `food2` etc. and `removeThis` in your code? Show a full [MCVE].

Comment: Use "else if" for the consecutive ifs in the code. If all conditions will be "if" it will execute all of them.

Comment: Show your html code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use "else if" for the consecutive ifs in the code. If all conditions will be "if" it will execute all of them.

Answer (score 1):

More number of same variable validation better with use `switch` instead of `if`

```
$(".removeFood").click(function() {
  $(this).text('')
  switch (removeThis.trim()) {
    case food1.trim():
      $("#newFoodName1").text('')
      break;
      // like wise
  }
})
```

Comment: This is great thank you! What are the benefits of using switch/case over else if

Comment: [read this](https://medium.com/the-daily-standup/javascript-switch-statement-vs-if-else-if-ee3111793fa0) .Switch created for the main purpose only `More no of same variable condition`. easy to readable and more efficient